# What does 'reel in' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *"That month, federal officials disclosed that Smith admitted to parking $200 million in offshore accounts and criminally evaded paying taxes on it for 15 years—from 2000 through 2015. Smith entered into a non-prosecution agreement with the Department of Justice and agreed to pay $139 million in penalties to the IRS—the largest tax fine ever. He also agreed to help the IRS **reel in** Texas-based billionaire Robert Brockman, Smith’s former client at Goldman Sachs and reportedly the initial investor in his Vista Equity private equity firm. Brockman was charged in October with hiding $2 billion from tax officials in offshore accounts, perhaps the largest tax evasion scheme in history."*

What does **'reel in'** mean here? Does it mean **'to investigate'**, or **'to arrest'**?

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/lisettevoytko/2021/12/27/here-are-the-biggest-billionaire-scandals-of-2020/?sh=284a4b117a19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Reel in' is a fishing metaphor. The idea is that the person you want to catch is stuck on the end of the fishing line, but there is still some work to do before finishing the job (getting hold of the fish). In this case, the remaining work was obviously to find / investigate / charge / build a case against Brockman.